# Jekyll CMS Insert Language data file into another data file

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

Insertion of language definition data yml is not being parsed into another datafile before or after presentation.

I've tried using liquid tags.

front-end code presentation

```
<div class="small-6 medium-3 large-3 columns">
            {% for network_item in site.data.network %}
              {% if forloop.first == true %}
                <h5 class="shadow-black">{{ network_item.menu_name }}</h5>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

This is the data file for network.yml still a WIP:

```
- menu_name: "{{ site.data.language.menu_name }}"

- name: "Icons by Daniel Bruce"
  url: "http://entypo.com/"
  class: "network-entypo"
  title: "Icons by Daniel Bruce"

- name: "Built on Foundation"
  url: "http://foundation.zurb.com/"
  class: "services-newsletter"
  title: "Built on Foundation"

- name: "Images by Unsplash"
  url: "http://unsplash.com/"
  class: "rss-link"
  title: "Images by Unsplash"

- name: "Using Backstretch by Scott Robbin"
  url: "http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/"
  class: "sitemap-link"
  title: "Using Backstretch by Scott Robbin"
```

Here's the language item from language.yml

```
menu_name: "Credits"
```

In the front-end rendered code I'm getting a title of:

```
{{ SITE.DATA.LANGUAGE.MENU_NAME }}
```

This should be the language definition so I can make this theme multilingual.

Comment: I changed the front-end code to:  <h5 class="shadow-black">{{ site.data.language.menu_name }}</h5> and that worked. Other items have to be translatable, still.